# StandardError redirect to page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, error-handling

I was handed a project that another developer worked on, without leaving any documentation behind.  The code fetches some purchases from a shopping website, looks for a price and notifies the user.

The app may encounter errors like "no results found" and then I raise a standarderror.

I want to redirect the user to the error page and notify them about it but I can't do that because it isn't a controller, so the `redirect_to` option doesn't work.

services/purchase_checker.rb is called once an hour:

```
      def call
        user.transaction do
          store_purchase
          if better_purchase?
            update_purchase
          end
        end
      rescue MyError=> e
        store_error(e)
      end



def store_error(error)
    user.check_errors.create!(error_type: error.class.name, message: error.message)
  end
```

services/my_error.rb:

```
class MyError< StandardError

  def initialize(error_type, error_message)
    super(error_message)
    @error_type = error_type
  end

  attr_reader :error_type

end
```

services/purchase_fetcher.rb:

```
def parse_result_page
    raise purchase_form_page.error if purchase_form_page.error.present?
    offer = purchase_page.map{|proposal_section| 
            propose(proposal_section, purchase) }
                            .min_by(&:price)

    offer or raise MyError.new("No results", "No results could be found")
  end
```

Comment: Can you post the controller action and where PurchaseChecker#call gets called?

Comment: it's called by an activejob

Comment: What you're after is unclear: If the job runs every hour, where in the request/response cycle do you propose having the user be redirected?

Comment: Okay, now seeing the comments below that it's after the initial search...

Comment: it's executed the first time right after the user makes the search. then it should notify him if no results were found. if they are, he'll be notified of a better price every hour... sorry for being unclear, English isn't my language

Comment: Welcome to SO. It'd be useful for you to read "[ask]", including the links on that page. We don't care if you're new or old to a language. We care if you did your homework, researched, researched, researched, tried and tried again, then wrote a well-thought-out question. Telling us you searched the "whole web" doesn't help. If you search and can't find information, tell us where you searched and why it didn't help, otherwise show us your effort by providing runnable code that demonstrates the problem. "[mcve]" explains this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is running in a job, the best way to notify the user would be by email, or some other async notification method. When an error is detected, an email is sent.

If that's not an option for some reason, you can check if a user has `check_errors` in any relevant controllers. Looking at the `store_error(error)` method that is called when an error is found, it seems it's creating a new record in the Database to log the error. You should be able to check if a user has any error logged via the `user.check_errors` relationship.

You could do it like this, for example:

```
class SomeController < ActionController::Base
  # ...
  before_action :redirect_if_check_errors

  # ...

  def redirect_if_check_errors
    # Assuming you're using Devise or something similar
    if current_user && current_user.check_errors.exists?
      redirect_to some_error_page_you_create_for_this_path
    end
  end
end
```

This will check for these errors in every action of `SomeController` and redirect the user to an error page you should create, where you render the errors in the `user.check_errors` relationship.

There are multiple ways to do this, but I still think sending an email from the Job is a better option if you want to actively notify the user. Or perhaps add an interface element that warns the user whenever `user.check_errors` has stuff there, for example.

Answer (score 1):

you should create another err class, eg `NotFoundError`:

```
offer or raise NotFoundError.new("No results", "No results could be found")
```

then in your controller:

```
begin
  parse_result_page
rescue NotFoundError => e
  redirect_to err_page, :notice => e.message
end
```

Comment: I don't have a controller for this object. The error is raised in another object. and because it's not a controller I can't use redirect

Comment: if you wan't to notify the user, than you shouldn't use an background job,because it's async, you can't get the feedback in time

Comment: it's executed the first time right after the user makes a search.. then it should notify him there are no results

Answer (score 0):

I propose that you do this synchronously so that the response can happen directly in the request/response cycle. Perhaps something like this:

`# controller`

```
def search
  # do your searching
  # ...
  if search_results.blank?
    # call model method, but do it synchrously
    purchase_check = PurchaseChecker.call
  end

  if purchase_check.is_a?(MyError) # Check if it's your error
    redirect_to(some_path, flash: { warning: "Warn them"})
  end
end
```

`# model, say PurchaseChecker`

```
def call
  # do your code
rescue MyError => e
  store_error(e)
  e # return the error so that the controller can do something with it
end
```